# Free software to audit pdf file size

Tags: gratis, pdf

I'm looking for a free (preferably Windows) tool that can give a break-down of a .pdf file's size into images, fonts, text and whatever else makes up a .pdf file.

Adobe Reader Pro and PDF Studio Pro both have audit features that show what percentage of a .pdf file is taken up by different components.

Examples (Adobe Reader and PDF Studio Pro):

[image]
[image]

Comment: Great question.  Do you happen to have a sample report from Adobe Reader Pro or PDF Studio Pro that you can post?